# Spring boot 2.3.5 | publish jar to local maven repository using gradle is not working

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to publish a `spring-boot` project to local maven repository using `Gradle`. however, I'm getting below error.

[image: These are the Gradle tasks and out put]

My `Gradle` file looks like below

```js
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'maven'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR9")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Thanks,

---

I have changed the script to following and still it not working

below is the `gradle` tasks, error message and script

```js
D:\workspaces\test\common>gradle clean publishToMavenLocal
> Task :publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'mavenLocal'
   > Artifact common-1.0.jar wasn't produced by this build.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

```js
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '1.0'

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR9")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releasesRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/releases"
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/snapshots"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}

javadoc {
    if(JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()) {
        options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
    }
}
```

however if remove dependencies, it's working fine

this script is working

```js
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'signing'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            versionMapping {
                usage('java-api') {
                    fromResolutionOf('runtimeClasspath')
                }
                usage('java-runtime') {
                    fromResolutionResult()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            def releasesRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/releases"
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = "$buildDir/repos/snapshots"
            url = version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}



javadoc {
    if(JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()) {
        options.addBooleanOption('html5', true)
    }
}
```

any idea why my script is not working ??

Thanks

Comment: where is your publish section?

Comment: Nitesh: He is using the [old and deprecated Maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html).

Comment: Nitesh and Bjorn
I have updated the script and still no working. iv updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `org.springframework.boot` plugin and used the below method to add dependencies and it worked. I would appreciate if someone can share if there is a document with this information.
this is the change I made

```js
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

to

```js
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.3.8.RELEASE'
}
```

and

```js
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

to

```js
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```